# How do I attach a roof ledger to an exterior wall?

Tags: framing, roofing, flashing

I have a Trex deck and perimeter railing, similar to this web photo.
I have a wood clapboard siding. I want to build a roof (like the photo), install support columns and create a three season screened deck room.
I am an advanced beginner.

How do I securely attach, I believe it is called a Ledger Board, to the house for roof support as pointed to by the arrow?

I know I need flashing - Any other standards I should follow? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty vague question, and is probably off-topic as such. A suitably vague answer is that you open the siding, install the ledger with appropriate lag bolts into framing, flash around it, and replace the siding. There are probably many diagrams to be found online.

Comment: You may need a permit for such an installation. Check with your local authority.

Comment: @chris_cudmore That is an issue I didn't think of, thanks for responding